# How do I develope webpages for the iphone that look like native apps?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css

If you look at some google pages (ie. mail.google.com/tasks) on the iphone they look a lot like native iphone apps. Does anyone know how they got it to mimic the look of the native apps and is there a resource that describes how to do it?

Also does one have access to any of the iphone hardware data ( ie. accelerometer data, gps information ) from the javascript on the clients safari browser? I imagine not but I thought I would ask anyway.

Comment: I found a stackoverflow thread that asks essentially the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215390/available-iphone-web-application-javascript-ui-library-frameworks 
Sorry for the duplication, I didn't see it initially.

Comment: Well I found a link that states that at least GPS information is available through a web app! http://www.ismashphone.com/2009/07/iphone-safari-webapps-now-have-gps-functionality.html
This is great news but I am still unsure if we can get access to other information (compass, accelerometer, etc... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Google search for "HTML iphone" yields heaps of answers. You need to pay close attention to the conditional HTML for the iphone. This article seems to cover a lot of information needed for the look/feel: [iphone-development-12-tips](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/iphone-development-12-tips)

I also stumbled across an API that might be of some use:
[http://code.google.com/p/iui](http://code.google.com/p/iui/wiki/Introduction). They have some live demos:

- [Music Example](http://iui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/REL-current/samples/music.html#_home)
- [Digg Mockup](http://iui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/REL-current/samples/digg/index.html#___1__)

Comment: Both of those links where spot on! Very nice.

Answer (score 4):

This article talks about how you can make your website iPhone friendly : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeYourWebsiteMobileAndIPhoneFriendlyAddHomeScreenIPhoneIconsAndAdjustTheViewPort.aspx

To answer your second question I would like to direct you towards "Phonegap" (http://phonegap.com/) which is an open source development tool for building fast, easy mobile apps with JavaScript and supports accessing geolocation and accelerometer data for the iPhone.

Comment: PhoneGap, of course is only for building apps. Doesn't help you build web pages intended for Mobile Safari.

Comment: Hi, this is not a comment to this answer, but we've noticed you deleted a lot of your answers recently. Unless the answers are flat out wrong, outdated, or similarly bad, try to avoid that. If you have questions, feel free to ask.