# how to define in which programming was developed the application

Tags: windows, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine source language from a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704202/determine-source-language-from-a-binary)

There is a compiled application (com, exe, etc.).

I want to ask, whether there is any method to recognize in which programming language the application was developed (c#, Delphi, Visual Basic, Visual C++, etc.)?

Comment: look at the executables header....

Comment: @MitchWheat - That will do to a limited amount (.NET vs native C/C++), though not all languages.

Comment: Ask the programmer.  If you don't know the programmer and don't have the source then it really doesn't matter that you know since you cannot do anything useful with the info.

Comment: @Oded: sure it's limited. That's why it's a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can  use [PEiD](http://www.peid.info/), this tool has been discontinued., but the last version still working.

> PEiD detects most common packers, cryptors and compilers for PE files.
>   It can currently detect more than 600 different signatures in PE
>   files.