# Designing Rich Website for Android & Iphone

Tags: android, xhtml, mobile, iphone, mobile-website

My team and I are currently planning to do some Rich Web development for the android and iphone and I am wondering if you guys could share some resources with us. Anything will be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this SO question: [Available iPhone Web Application JavaScript UI Library/Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215390/available-iphone-web-application-javascript-ui-library-frameworks) - the answers list off various iPhone web app frameworks, and a useful link to http://distractable.net/coding/iphone-android-web-application-frameworks/. These are all HTML5 based and therefore will work on Android too. There are not any Android specific frameworks that I know of.

Mind you, its debatable if you want to use an iPhone webapp framework that gives native look & feel on Android because the user will have Android device but will have iPhone user experience - which may be confusing.

Have you considered just using something like jQuery  & jQuery UI ?  iPhone & Android support both of these and they can be used to develop rich apps.  **Update:** http://jqtouch.com/ is jquery based and while I haven't had chance to use it yet, it looks pretty good.

One other thing to bear in mind that users will be accessing your site on limited 2G/3G connections so don't lose track of the download size of your web app.

Comment: yeah i looked at jqtouch, but i was wondering if it wasn't an overkill for a mobile app

Comment: How rich does your mobile web app need to be? Gmail type richness, or just some useful js validation type stuff?

Comment: Yeah Gmail. We wanna do some ajax and some html5 stuff. So thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "do HTML5" stuff, then I'd recommend that you look at our demos and other stuff at www.sencha.com/products/touch - although if you think jQTouch is overkill, then Touch will definitely be even more overkill [I work for the company]