# How do i develop iOS Apps with Webkit ? Need Webkit starters Help

Tags: iphone, ios, webkit, cross-platform

I wanted to learn this web app technology and develop cross platform apps for iOS, Andriod and other webkit supported platforms.. 
Any help and guide for the same will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone web applications, templates, frameworks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756/iphone-web-applications-templates-frameworks)

Comment: Oh thats a great help. Maybe I didnt notice that duplicate. Let me see thru this and learn the best. And yeah thanks for closing the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for iPhone

http://www.wowebook.org/safari-and-webkit-development-for-iphone-os-3-0.html

for android : http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=369 [+ Basics ]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot karthik.... really a great material... but instead of books, can you plz suggest some links or steps to be followed.Steps in the sense any sequences?