# What frameworks can be used to create mobile web apps that are indistinguishable from native iOS apps

Tags: ios, mobile

I'd like to know which framework you use to create mobile web applications that are - from a user's point of view - virtually indistinguishable from a native iOS app. Please provide a link do an actual application that has been built with said framework.
I mean more than just the look of a navigation bar and a back button, but an app that also *feels* like a native app, with the same smooth scrolling and transition animations of native apps.

To clarify: This is research in connection with this article: http://www.springenwerk.com/2011/09/thoughts-on-mobile-ui-design.html

Comment: Please let me know why you down-vote the question and give me chance to clarify or explain.

Comment: I imagine the downvote is because "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." (from the FAQ)

Comment: @jrturton Fair enough, I'll make it more practical and answerable. Although it is an actual problem I (and I think many others) face.

Comment: It's also been voted to close as off-topic, as it's not a specific programming question. "How to emulate iOS native scrolling in a web app" or something would probably get better treatment.

Comment: @jrturton you're probably right. What about moving it to "programmers.stackexchange.com" or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone web applications, templates, frameworks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756/iphone-web-applications-templates-frameworks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Financial Times app is indistinguishable. That said, I think they discontinued the App store app.

http://apps.ft.com/ftwebapp/

You don't even see the safari browser bar in the web app. I don't know how that works though. Not a web - dev.